# How to install FFMPEG on Node/Meteor server?

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, meteor

I'm working on a meteor project where I need support of ffmpeg for converting the audio files. I'm able to do this in my local system in meteor language. When I'm pushing the code to live server I am facing an issue

```
                  "/bin/sh: 1: ffmpeg: not found".
```

I didn't install ffmpeg on server. I do't know how to install it on meteor server. If anyone knows about it let me know, that will be very useful for me.

I appreciate your help.

Thanks.

Comment: I think what you really want to know is how to install FFmpeg on a Linux or Windows server, and for that you should check out SuperUser.com.  The easiest thing to do is find a pre-built binary, but this isn't always possible depending on your specific needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to get access via ssh to apps on meteor.com & I don't think allow to use custom binaries on their infrastructure.

Each instance is in a sort of vm which doesn't give you root access so we can't make any binaries.

If we want to use ffmpeg/custom binaries with our app we would have to use our own infrastructure like on heroku (which is also free), AWS or digitalocean.

The Dev-Ops that meteor deploy affords is a deployment of the bundled meteor app only. There is no other access (ftp, ssh, or otherwise) given besides the mongo database (via meteor mongo